# Washing hand on bread after praying (With a brocho?)

Tags: halacha, blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing

If I just prayed (I washed hands before prayer) Shachrit (same question by minha)
should I make a blessing when washing my hands for bread (if I am eating in the same place I prayed)?
or are we worried that my hands are clean from before Shachrit and I should wash without a blessing?

Sources please?
(I am not looking for a halachik decision but Sources)

Answer (score 1):

If when you washed for prayer you intended for the washing to count for eating bread later, and you were careful the whole time not to dirty your hands (which you'd be careful about anyway during prayer), then you do not need to wash again for the bread, though if water is readily available then it is good to wash again without a blessing. (Shulchan Arukh [OC 164:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%93_%D7%90))

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara (Berachos 42a) writes that there mustn't be a hefsek between washing and eating. Seemingly, this would include davening.

Hagahos Maimoniyos (Berachos 6:17) mentions a Machlokes amongst the Geonim as to whether one could wash one's hands once for both *asher yatzar* and bread. What's important is that there is no hefsek (which would be a problem in your scenario). The Mordechai (Berachos 204) stresses that there mustn't be a hefsek between washing and the meal - hence one couldn't say *asher yatzar* before eating.

See the [Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.165.1?lang=bi) and [Mishna Berura](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.165.2?lang=bi)

[Teshuvos Vehanhagos 1:170:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=127&hilite=) discusses scratching one's head or doing something similar to ensure that one is required to wash for 'netilas yadayim' thus ensuring that there is no safek (doubt)

The Chazon Ish ([OC 25:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14336&st=&pgnum=80)) writes that in this scenario, one would have to wash again with a beracha

Rabbi Kaganoff has a [wonderful article](http://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/netilas-yadayim/) discussing the different reasons for washing. Washing before Davening isn't the same as washing before eating bread.

Comment: +1 My question was about the brocho (if to make it) is not the problem of hefsek only between the brocho and the eating (and between the washing and the brocho) but if no brocho hefsek is not a problem?

Comment: The Gemara says that ideally we don't make a hefsek between washing and the blessing. Most understand that to be about Mayim Acharonim. Even if you take the minority opinion that it applies to washing before bread, it's not a problem Bedieved. Why is this answer getting upvoted? It doesn't address the question. It just discusses workarounds that can make you have to wash for sure.

Comment: if there's been a hefsek - then either way one would need to wash again properly - with a bracha.
See the Teshuvos Vehanhagos that I quoted - he specifically mentions scratching as a hefsek would make the beracaha a beracha levatala

Comment: @DoubleAA I have added the Chazon Ish who makes the point more clearly.

Comment: Dirtying your hands is indeed obviously a break and would need new washing (the old washing is entirely negated!). Davening or just waiting (a hefesk) is not a problem, at least bedieved. Moreover, anyway there is no problem of Hefsek if the washing was for something else too. This answer is inaccurate (or at least not applicable).

Comment: @DoubleAA this might be a good source http://www.chabad.org/3323479/

Comment: @hazoriz OC 164 is the source in my answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's how I found this (I +1 your answer)